# Get nth object of jquery selector array

Tags: jquery

As an example, I want to get the scroll positon of the second object in this selector-array

```
alert($("#sites > div").eq(2).scrollTop());
```

I know it'S dead simple, but I just can't seem to get it right..

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero-based in JavaScript. So the second object is at position `1`. Hence you would have to use `eq(1)` instead of `eq(2)`.

Comment: Whoops, forgot about that. However, it still won't work, it will always have a "0" in it. I found the "solution" though (answered it myself).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the little mistake that Vivin pointed out (wasn't too relevant here), I just misunderstood the function scrollTop. What I was looking for is this:

```
alert($("#sites > div").eq(1).position().top);
```

Stupid me, but it was late yesterday when I ran into this issue, so that's my excuse.